# Tikz inside other tikz produces empty output

Tags: tikz-pgf

My intentions are to produce a partially opaque image.

The idea I have used to achieve the goal:

File A

- create a tikz image [this is a complicated part].

File B

- include File A in scope + opacity using `\import`
- create a complex `\path[clip]` and include File A in this scope (with clipping).

The result using `\includestandalone` inside `\node` worked (see an image below). However, importing the result into a third file revealed scaling problems, i.e. clipping part of File B was not scaled as expected. (Maybe, this is my real problem).

[image: an expected output using \includestandalone inside the \node]

So, I have removed `\node`+`\includestandalone` and backed up to use `\import`, which I already use in File C to include File A (and it works without any issues).

Unfortunately, now it just creates

> an empty output in File B.

Debugging Note 1: File B `\import`s File A inside the `\tikzpicture` environment, while File C does it in a plain manner.

Debugging Note 2: adding `\draw` of 1-2 page long rectangle depicts File A, though rectangle is not drawn.

Since MWE [i.e. push a simple drawing into File A] just works as expected, I suppose the problem is in my real code and the fact that I use large, though scaled down, images inside File A.

File A code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{0}
\newcommand\righttrees{-35, -33, -30, -29, -26, -22, -21, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -11, -9, -7, -5, -3, -2, 1, 3, 4, 5}
\newcommand\lefttrees{-35, -32, -31, -30, -26, -22, -21, -20, -16, -15, -13, -11, -8, -7, -4, -3, -1, 1, 5, 6}
\newcommand\GreenCars{1/0, 1/1}
\newcommand\RedCars{0/1, 2/1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,rotate=-90, scale = 2]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{9}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hugelength}{250}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\slotlength}{1.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\carscalefactor}{0.03}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\treecalefactor}{0.01}
        
        
        \fill[black!20] (0, 0) rectangle (\length, \m);
        \foreach \y in {0, \m}
        {
            \draw[line width = 0.5mm, yellow!90] (0,\y) -- (\length, \y);
        }
        
        % the on-road marks move, clip most of it
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\distance cm]
            \clip (-\distance, -1) rectangle (\length-\distance, \m + 1);
            \foreach \y in {2, 3, ..., \m}
            {
                \draw[line width = 0.3mm, dash pattern=on 9pt off 27pt, white] (-\hugelength,\y - 1) -- (\length, \y - 1);
            }
        \end{scope}
            
        \begin{scope}% removed offset requirements: outer code should handle trees moving
            % just make sure there are no artefacts outside the frame
            \clip (0, -1) rectangle (\length, \m + 1);
            % tree outside the rightmost lane
            \foreach \xtree in \righttrees
            {
                \node at (\xtree, \m + 0.5) {\includegraphics[scale=\treecalefactor]{39-fir-tree-png-image}};
            }
            % tree outside the leftmost lane
            \foreach \xtree in \lefttrees
            {
                \node at (\xtree, -0.5) {\includegraphics[scale=\treecalefactor]{39-fir-tree-png-image}};
            }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0.9, 0.5)}]
            \foreach \x/\y in \GreenCars% in { (1 * \slotlength, 0), (1 * \slotlength, 1)}
            {
                \node at (\x * \slotlength, \y) {\scalebox{-1}{\includegraphics[scale=\carscalefactor]{GreenCarTopView}}};
            }
            \foreach \x/\y in \RedCars% in { (0 * \slotlength, 1), (2 * \slotlength, 1)}
            {
                \node at (\x * \slotlength, \y) {\scalebox{-1}{\includegraphics[scale=\carscalefactor]{RedCarTopView}}};
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

File B (with most of the code commented out)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
%
%\tikzset{
%   hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
%   hatch distance=10pt,
%   hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
%   hatch thickness=2pt
%}
%
%\makeatletter
%\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
%{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
%{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
%{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
%{
%   \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
%   \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
%   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
%   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
%   \pgfusepath{stroke}
%}
%\makeatother

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\newcommand\righttrees{}
\newcommand\lefttrees{}
\newcommand\GreenCars{}
\newcommand\RedCars{}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background rectangle]
        \renewcommand\lefttrees{1.60,8.20,9.20,10.20,13.20}
        \renewcommand\righttrees{5.60,9.20,10.20}
        \renewcommand\GreenCars{3.00/0.00,5.00/0.00,1.00/2.00,2.00/2.00,4.00/3.00}
        \renewcommand\RedCars{0.00/0.00,1.00/0.00,2.00/0.00,4.00/0.00,0.00/1.00,1.00/1.00,3.00/1.00,4.00/1.00,4.00/2.00,1.00/3.00,3.00/3.00,5.00/2.00}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{8.2}
        
        %\begin{scope}%[opacity=0.5]
            \import{./}{Frame.Moving.Cars}
            %\input{./Frame.Moving.Cars}
        %\draw[fill=green, opacity=0.3] (0,-10) rectangle (12, 25);
        %\end{scope}
        
        %\begin{scope}
        %   \pgfmathsetmacro{\basicunit}{1}
        %   \pgfmathsetmacro{\corneroffset}{0.1}
        %   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xslide}{2 * \basicunit - 2 * \corneroffset}
        %   \pgfmathsetmacro{\yslide}{3 * \basicunit - 2 * \corneroffset}
        %   \path[clip] (2-2*\basicunit, 2-7 * \basicunit) --
        %       ++ (0, -\basicunit + \corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (180:270:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0,0) arc (90:0:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, -\yslide) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (180:270:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (270:360:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, \yslide) --
        %       ++ (0,0) arc (180:90:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (270:360:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, \yslide) --
        %       ++ (0,0) arc (0:90:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (-\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (270:180:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, \yslide) --
        %       ++ (0,0) arc (0:90:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (-\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (90:180:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (0, -\yslide) --
        %       ++ (0,0) arc (0:-90:\corneroffset) --
        %       ++ (-\xslide, 0) --
        %       ++ (0, 0) arc (90:180:\corneroffset) --
        %       cycle
        %       ;
        %   \import{.}{Frame.Moving.Cars}
        %   \draw[pattern=flexible hatch, hatch distance=10pt, hatch thickness=1pt] 
        %       (4*\basicunit,-6*\basicunit) rectangle +(2 * \basicunit, 3 * \basicunit);
        %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The [tree PNG](https://freepngimg.com/thumb/fir%20tree/39-fir-tree-png-image.png) I used and saved in images directory (1924 x 1768).
Cars come from [car icons](https://www.iconspng.com/image/19165/green-racing-car-top-view) (960 x 476).

Can't be sure that above are original links to files I have at hand.

So my question is What should I fix?

However, it could be possible that my true question is how to draw on the included `tikzpicture`?

Comment: I do not know where is is written, but people on this site agrees - it is a bad idea to put one `tikzpicture` into an other. Your example is horrible - please see this guide: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Maybe could you provide a sketch of the intended output, because you would wait some time before someone really wants to dig into your code. And nesting `tikzpicture` gives unpredictable issues.

Comment: The usual solution  is to put one tikzpicture into a savebox the use `\node {\usebox...}; `  Of course, if you are using standalone you can just use \includgraphics with the PDF image.

Comment: @SebGlav, I have added an expected output. I will also add an image that made me change the John Kornmylo's approach - to show the scale-break effect

Comment: Basically, I think there is no need in solution (and it could be some local issue of mine). I have used a `\resizebox` to include the image, and it scaled properly. Have no idea, why i did not use it in the first place.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, I do not agree with you. As I wrote, MWE is inapplicable, cause it works AS EXPECTED locally, so I can't ask a question regarding the issue I do not expect MWE to present.